# Reference a specific class method with @see command using Doxygen

Tags: objective-c, doxygen, documentation-generation

I was not able to reference a specific class method using the doxygen @see command.

Suppose I have a class Server with a method start like below

```
@interface Server : NSObject

- (void) start:(NSInteger) mask;

@end
```

And suppose I have another class that has an object of Server.

```
@interface RandomNumberGeneration

/// How can I reference the method start from 
/// class server using the command @see
/// @see ????
+ (NSInteger) generate;

@end
```

So, is there a way to reference the method start of class Server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copied from [here](http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-i/)

> @see text | URL | classname | classname#methodname Use this to tag to
>   refer the reader to some other source of related information.

So I guess it should be:

```
/// @see Server#start:
```

Comment: +1 for the link to the blog post - a great introduction to using doxygen with Objective-C.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Has this changed recently? Using Xcode 5

Comment: Pretty late to the party, but make sure the method you are targeting with your `@see` has doxygen docs attached to it. My `@see` links weren't working until I added documentation to the methods that were being pointed at.

Comment: @ChrisSprague or  doxygen file should contain flag to generate entries for undocumennted entities

Answer (score 6):

See the doxygen manual page [Automatic link generation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html) for more information on referencing classes and functions. In particular see the section "Links to Functions".

Typically, I use the function refernce pattern

```
<className>::<functionName>
```

So in your case, I would use

```
/// \see Server::start
```

However, from the doxygen manual

> For JavaDoc compatibility a # may be used instead of a :: in the patterns above

as stated in @PeterG.'s answer.

For completeness, note that if you a reference a member in the same class

> In the documentation of a class containing a member foo, a reference to a global variable is made using `::foo`, whereas `#foo` will link to the member.